# Return element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Good day,

How can I return the element I removed on click..

```
$( "a#pull" ).click(function() {
  $( ".search" ).remove();
});
```

Basically, I just want to remove the element on click and I want the class .search to return back after another click again. What code will I add?

Sorry I'm super new in jquery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to remove the `.search` element from the DOM entirely, or can you just hide it?

One approach to this problem could be to just toggle a CSS class on that element to control it's visibility by using [jQuerys `.toggleClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

For this to work, you would need to adjust your JS as follows:

```
$( "a#pull" ).click(function() {
  // This will toggle or alternate the presence of the 
  // 'hidden' class on the '.search' element    
  $( ".search" ).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

You would also need to add the following CSS selector:

```
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly... Btw, I forgot I need to add 2 classes... Where will I put the other class... like class .return_link

Comment: Not sure I understand, however you may find this helpful:

`$( ".search" ).addClass('return_link')`

Comment: What I mean is... I need 2 classes to be hidden...  .search and .return_link sorry I forgot to add that to my main question..

Comment: Okay I think I understand, try this: `$( ".search, .return_link" ).toggleClass('hidden');`

Comment: You're welcome, all the best with your project - PM me if you need any more help :-)